# Why this erlang function is undefined?

Tags: elixir

```
iex(1)> a = :erlang.timestamp
{1458, 585479, 931609}
iex(2)> b = :erlang.timestamp
{1458, 585484, 197713}
iex(3)> :erlang.now_diff(a,b)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: :erlang.now_diff/2
    :erlang.now_diff({1458, 585479, 931609}, {1458, 585484, 197713})
```

So I can access erlang functions in elixir, accessing them by `:erlang`, but [now_diff/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html) is undefined.

I have a thought that this timer is not standard erlang module, and needed to be required/imported, but I can't figure out how?

P.S. Don't advice timex instead if it doesn't have function to calculate timestamps diff with high precision like this erlang function. I didn't find reading docs.

Comment: Try `:timer.now_diff(a, b)`

Comment: @helios35 is right, but just for the sake of completeness, timex has such function: https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/master/lib/time/time.ex#L391 It even uses `:timer.now_diff/2` inside :)

Comment: @tkowal, well, it is not documented on main page

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the case with most libraries. It might be good to search for them on hex.pm and check out online docs there (they are generated from the source code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
:timer.now_diff(a, b)
```

Functions are not prefixed with `:erlang` because they are erlang functions, but because they are part of the `erlang` module. now_diff is part of the timer module, hence you would use `:timer` instead of `:erlang`.